# Send SMS with Delivery Report

Tags: c#, sms, windows

I Use [GSM Communication Library (GSMComm)](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm) for send and receive SMS with GSM modem. How Can I Send Sms With Delivery Report? How Can I get Status of Send Messages?

Comment: are you looking for free or paid service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sms+c%23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you first read all messages from the SIM (since status report msg is sent as sms back to your SIM from the provider you use). 
Iterate through these msgs and filter out the status msgs.
You must have saved the id of the sent sms from your mobile
`data.Status.ToString()`
:

```
GsmCommMain comm = new GsmCommMain(port, baundRate, timeout);
//.... Other code may goes here
// Read all SMS messages from the storage
    DecodedShortMessage[] messages = comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, 
    PhoneStorageType.Sim );// Or PhoneStorageType.Phone
    foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
        {
          if (((SmsPdu)message.Data) is SmsStatusReportPdu)
          {
                //HERE WE'LL GET THE STATUS REPORT
                SmsStatusReportPdu data = (SmsStatusReportPdu)message.Data;
                //Recipient: data.RecipientAddress
                //Status: data.Status.ToString()
                //Timestamp: data.DischargeTime.ToString()
                //Message ref (ID of the sent sms from the mobile): data.MessageReference.ToString()


      }
    }
```