# SMS Delivery Report using GSMComm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used GSMComm API for sending sms to the clients from sql database. I have read the given answer from [Send SMS with Delivery Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526539/send-sms-with-delivery-report), but it is not worked. I have checked RequestStatusReport to true when sending sms and get the status report with comm_MessageReceived() event. But from this event I get only index and storage of the status report. I want the number (RecipientAddress) for which or from which this status report has came. But when I use code to get that, it returns null value. I will be very grateful if anyone give a solution. I am using 3g modem for sending sms.

```
/*Message Receive Event*/
    private void comm_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            IMessageIndicationObject obj = e.IndicationObject;

            if (obj is MemoryLocation) //Get status report for this condition
            {
                MemoryLocation loc = (MemoryLocation)obj;
                Output(string.Format("New message received in storage \"{0}\", index {1}.",
                    loc.Storage, loc.Index));
                Output("");
                SmsStatusReportPdu pdu = new SmsStatusReportPdu();
                ShowMessage(pdu);
                return;
            }

            if (obj is ShortMessage)
            {
                ShortMessage msg = (ShortMessage)obj;
                SmsPdu pdu = comm.DecodeReceivedMessage(msg);
                Output("New message received:");
                ShowMessage(pdu);
                Output("");
                return;
            }
            Output("Error: Unknown notification object!");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowException(ex);
        }
    }

private void ShowMessage(SmsPdu pdu)
{
   if (pdu is SmsSubmitPdu)
{
// Stored (sent/unsent) message
SmsSubmitPdu data = (SmsSubmitPdu)pdu;
Output("SENT/UNSENT MESSAGE");
Output("Recipient: " + data.DestinationAddress);
Output("Message text: " + data.UserDataText);
Output("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
return;
}
   if (pdu is SmsDeliverPdu)
{
// Received message
SmsDeliverPdu data = (SmsDeliverPdu)pdu;
Output("RECEIVED MESSAGE");
Output("Sender: " + data.OriginatingAddress);
Output("Sent: " + data.SCTimestamp.ToString());
Output("Message text: " + data.UserDataText);
Output("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
return;
}
    if (pdu is SmsStatusReportPdu)
{
// Status report
SmsStatusReportPdu data = (SmsStatusReportPdu)pdu;
Output("STATUS REPORT");
Output("Recipient: " + data.RecipientAddress); //Null value
Output("Status: " + data.Status.ToString());
Output("Timestamp: " + data.DischargeTime.ToString());
Output("Message ref: " + data.MessageReference.ToString());
Output("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
return;
}
Output("Unknown message type: " + pdu.GetType().ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Hoped for someone who can give this answer...

Answer (score 0):

No wonder you get null RecipientAddress in the first case - you created an empty object instead of reading the message:
SmsStatusReportPdu pdu = new SmsStatusReportPdu()

this should work for delivery reports stored in SIM memory:

```
DecodedShortMessage msg = _comm.ReadMessage(ind.Index, ind.Storage);
SmsStatusReportPdu spdu = pdu as PDU.SmsStatusReportPdu;
if (spdu != null)
{
    //do something with the status report
    Console.WriteLine(spdu.RecipientAddress);
}
```